# Fix for cfloop adding unwanted white-space to a table in IE6?

Tags: html, css, coldfusion, internet-explorer-6

I'm forced to make this site compatible for IE6. I wish I didn't, but such is life.

Here's the problem. When I'm running the ***cfloop query="thisqueryName"*** it's adding about... 500-600px of whitespace at the top of a overflow-y:scroll table.

I've tried forcing the position of the top of the table up to compensate for the extra whitespace, but with no luck.

```
<div id="myDivid" >
<table id="thistablename">
    <!--- Here is the problem --->
<cfloop query="thisqueryname">
            <!--- End of Problem Code -->
    <cfquery name="thisotherqueryname" datasource="#Application.dsn#">
            SELECT  name
                    , frequency
                    , ninjaskills
            FROM    thistablename
            WHERE   tid = #ID#
                    AND status = 'A'
        </cfquery>
        <cfquery name="anotherqueryname" datasource="#Application.dsn#">
            SELECT  somestuffhere
            FROM    thisothertablenamehere
            WHERE   ID = #ID#
        </cfquery>
    <tr>
        <th class="numCol"></th> 
                   <!--- etc etc etc --->
```

(No, this is not my naming schema (: names have been changed to protect the innocent and all that)

Any fixes or helpful suggestions to get around this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you make a test case on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)? I want to see the generated HTML/CSS, not the server-side ColdFusion code. Make sure the test case reproduces the problem in IE6.

Comment: Well, I would have had to rewrite alot of it, since it's a intranet site and I wouldn't want some of the information public.

However, it finally hit me how to solve the problem... but it was in a way I didn't really like. Instead of looping through generating rows of the table, I just generated individual tables. Looks worse than I would have hoped, but not nearly as bad as when I had that huge amounts of white-space. 

(I did see your comment on my other question _after_ I deleted it. Sorry about that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several factors working against you. [Know what generates whitespace](http://cfbestpractices.blogspot.com/2012/03/understand-what-generates-whitespace.html) before you try to combat it.

1. Move your queries and loops to the top of the page, and wrap them in `<cfsilent>`.
2. Put the actual HTML you are generating inside a `<cfsavecontent>`.
3. Output the single `<cfsavecontent>` variable you've constructed down in the viewable area of your template (outside of the `<cfsilent>` call).
4. Be sure that, if you have something like an Application.cfc or Application.cfm, that you are adequately suppressing whitespace with by ensuring all your function calls have their output attribute set to false (for Application.cfc), or in the case of an Application.cfm, that you have a `<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly=true>` at the start...and a `<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly=false>` at the end.
5. If all else fails, and you still get whitespace at the start, you can "hack" in a suppressor with a `<cfcontent type="text/html; charset=UTF-8" reset="true" />`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a `<cfsilent>` around your queries. That should help.

Alternatively, set `<cfsetting enableCFoutputOnly = "yes">` at the top of the page then wrap only the portions you want to output within `<cfoutput>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to split what you're doing into two loops. Have the first loop manipulate your query with the data from your subsequent queries. Then the second loop would be purely for output. That should keep it from having a lot of extra whitespace in your table.

Answer (score 0):

set `<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true" />` at the top and `<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="false" />` at the bottom of the file and use `<cfoutput>...</cfoutput>` to specifically output content to the browser.  Only content within the cfoutput tags will be output to the screen, including whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfprocessingdirective suppressWhiteSpace = "yes">
```

alternatively, "Enable Whitespace Management" setting in the CF Administrator.